# How to graph lighttp mod_status apart from port 80 with cacti template

Tags: php, lighttpd, cacti

I use cacti as my main server monitoring tools. I done researching and found on cacti forum, how to graph using mod_status and using custom cacti template, but then i found problem when i use port apart from default 80, cacti fail to fetch traffic generated by mod_status. I asked question on cacti forum but they seem to dormant. [This is my asked question](http://forums.cacti.net/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=55947), and [this is my cacti template reference](http://forums.cacti.net/about19676.html). If i using default port 80, all seem to work.
Since php is not my native language, it forbid my to do any modification to the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your time, viewer. I found solution 
http://forums.cacti.net/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=55947&p=262334#p262334